# How to use a variable in a query with sp_send_dbmail?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a problem when trying to send a variable from the @ query, this variable is sent by a trigger, the variable goes well with the procedure, the print and show what I send, the problem occurs when I try to take that variable to select not I take the variable, just take the value of what I write.

The mail is working fine without problems if you only write text. I also take data from a normal query, but if I include a variable fails.

I chose to put the variable in the select so '+ @ q +' and displays the error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Facturacion_Tope, Line 29
>   Incorrect syntax near '+'.

and remove the single quote symbol `+` and is not a fixed value and variable

```
USE [sistemas]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Facturacion_Tope]    Script Date: 11/15/2012 07:32:29 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Facturacion_Tope]
    @ENVIO INT 
AS
print @ENVIO
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Declare @q INT
    --here shows the value of consultation 
    print @ENVIO

    set @q = (select OID from sistemas..DATFACTUR_DINAMICA WHERE OID = @ENVIO)

    --here shows the value of consultation
    print @q

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'correo_sistemas',
      @recipients = 'diegom_montes_contratista@clinica.com.co',
      -- @execute_query_database = 'sistemas',
      @query = 'select * from sistemas..DATFACTUR_DINAMICA WHERE OID = "@q"',                       
      @query_attachment_filename = 'Consulta.txt',      
      -- @body = 'Caida en: '@query+'', 
      @body_format = 'HTML',
      @subject = 'Numero de factura';
END
```

This is the output of the stored procedure.

> 209 --prints well
>   209 - prints well
>   HAY VA --prints well
>   209 --prints well
>   Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>   Error formatting query, probably invalid parameters
>   Doomed Error 14661 on line 504, Query execution failed: Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Server CDPALWIN01\CDPALSQL02, Line 1
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@q".
>   Msg 3903, Level 16, State 1, Procedure DEVDATFAC, Line 180
>   The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the @query parameter beforehand, and then use that as a simple variable rather than concatenating strings in the procedure parameter assignment.

```
 DECLARE @thequery nvarchar(max) = 'select * from sistemas..DATFACTUR_DINAMICA
                                    WHERE OID = ' + cast(@q as nvarchar(max));
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
 @profile_name = 'correo_sistemas',
    @recipients = 'diegom_montes_contratista@clinica.com.co',
   -- @execute_query_database = 'sistemas',
    @query = @thequery,                     
    @query_attachment_filename = 'Consulta.txt',      
  -- @body = 'Caida en: '@query+'', 
   @body_format = 'HTML',
    @subject = 'Numero de factura';
```

Comment: I have another problem regarding the issue

Comment: Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0 Error formatting query, probably invalid parameters Doomed Error 14661 on line 504, Query execution failed: CONSECUTIVO PERIODO VALOR_NETO CONTRATO FECHA_INGRESO DOCUME_ALTERNO -------------- -------- ----------------- ----------- ----------------------- -------------- SGPR0000127661 201212 259153978.00 4 2012-11-20 17:25:55.600 SGPR127661 Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted. –

Comment: there is a process that remains stuck -- Session ID User Process Login Database Task State Command Application Wait Time (ms) Wait Type Wait Resource Blocked By Head Blocker Memory Use (KB) Host Name Workload Group 203 1 DgEmpresal master SUSPENDED SELECT SQLCMD 52734 LCK_M_S keylock hobtid=72057594045726720 dbid=7 id=lockae0df100 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057594045726720 287 16 CDPALWIN01 default –

Answer (score -1):

use single quotes to to print variable as static value.

```
declare @s_dt nvarchar(max)

set @s_dt = 'select * from database.dbo.table_name where col_name = ''' + CAST(cast(getdate() as DATE) as nvarchar(max)) + ''''
```